# I got webpacker error when running the rails app. 'TypeError: environment.plugins.set is not a function'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, webpacker

Rails 5.1.5
webpacker 3.3.0

When I run the rails app, I got this compilation error and it does not work.

```
Compilation failed:
remote:        /tmp/build_074ca0ee678491d6f72035c60cc5f616/config/webpack/environment.js:5
remote:        environment.plugins.set('Provide',
remote:        ^
remote:        TypeError: environment.plugins.set is not a function
remote:        at Object.<anonymous> (/tmp/build_074ca0ee678491d6f72035c60cc5f616/config/webpack/environment.js:5:21)
remote:        at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found the solution by myself.

Changed `set` to `prepend` of `config/webpack/environment.js`.

Before

```
environment.plugins.set('Provide',
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery'
  })
)
```

After

```
environment.plugins.prepend('Provide',
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery'
  })
)
```

https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/1318
https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#330---2018-03-03